# Can't publish custom post type - "You are not allowed to edit this post."

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, post-meta, publish

Hey guys I've created this post type but when I click the publish button I receive the message:

> You are not allowed to edit this post.

Have I done something wrong in my code to disallow anyone from publishing a post of this custom type?  Here's the code:

```
<?php
function image_post_type(){
    $labels = array(
                'name'              =>  'Images',
                'singlular_name'    =>  'Image',
                'add_new'           =>  'Add New',
                'add_new_item'      =>  'Add New Image',
                'edit_item'         =>  'Edit Image',
                'new_item'          =>  'New Image',
                'all_items'         =>  'All Images',
                'view_item'         =>  'View Image',
                'search_items'      =>  'Search Images',
                'not_found'         =>  'No Images found',
                'not_found_in_trash'=>  'No Images found in Trash', 
                'parent_item_colon' =>  '',
                'menu_name'         =>  'Images'
            );

    $args = array(
                'labels'                =>  $labels,
                'public'                =>  true,
                'exclude_from_search'   =>  false,
                'publicly_queryable'    =>  true,
                'show_ui'               =>  true,
                'show_in_nav_menus'     =>  true,
                'show_in_menu'          =>  true,
                'menu_position'         =>  1,
                //'menu_icon'               =>  'icon32',
                'capability_type'       =>  'post',
                'map_meta_cap'          =>  false,
                'hierarchical'          =>  false,
                'supports'              =>  array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields'),
                'register_meta_box_cb'  =>  'add_meta_box_callback',
                'has_archive'           =>  true,
                'query_var'             =>  true,
                'can_export'            =>  true
            );

    register_post_type('image_post', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'image_post_type');

function add_meta_box_callback(){
    add_meta_box('image_variations', 'Image Variations', 'image_variations_callback', 'image_post', 'side', 'low');
}

function image_variations_callback(){

}

function add_image_post_type_to_query($query){
    if(is_home() && $query->is_main_query()){
        $query->set( 'post_type', array('post', 'page', 'image_post') );
    }
    return $query;
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your admin role when your are logging into the wp-admin? - I mean as Administrator/Editor/Author/Subscriber - What??

Comment: The default capability_type is post, so you could lose that element, along with the following 'map_meta_cap'.

Comment: It happened to me too, a few questions:
1. Did you update your permalink or made ​​flush rewrite rules after the registration of cpt?
2. You have accidentally changed the name registration for cpt and tried to update / edit / publish a post of that cpt?

Comment: @MayeenulIslam My role is the admin.

Comment: @vancoder I was just keeping them there just in case I needed to change them quickly cause I was partly doing this for learning purposes.

Comment: @iEmanuele No I did not do the first thing and I have changed the name but then I went back to the Dashboard page and back to trying to post again.  How would I go about doing the first thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default for `map_meta_cap` is actually ***not*** ***false*** if you're also passing in a `capability_type` of `post` or `page`, which you are.

The following code is in [Wordpress Core's post.php](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/post.php#L1205):

```
// Back compat with quirky handling in version 3.0. #14122
if ( empty( $args->capabilities ) && null === $args->map_meta_cap && in_array( $args->capability_type, array( 'post', 'page' ) ) )
    $args->map_meta_cap = true;
```

So by explicitly setting it to ***false***, you were telling it not to use the capabilities of a `post` or `page`.

By not setting it at all, you allowed the above code to set it to ***true***.

Code just [a few lines down](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/post.php#L1212), [get_post_type_capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type_capabilities) uses this flag for whether or not to use the default posts capabilities which gives you the permissions you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The CPT is now working.  I'm not sure why it's working but it is and here's what happened for me to make it start working.  Well I saw @hawkidoki's "answer" and how he didn't use variables so I reformatted mine to look the same (below) and ran it and it didn't work until I commented out **map_meta_cap**:

```
<?php
function image_post_type(){

    register_post_type('image_post', array(
                'labels'                =>  array(
                                                'name'              =>  'Images',
                                                'singlular_name'    =>  'Image',
                                                'add_new'           =>  'Add New',
                                                'add_new_item'      =>  'Add New Image',
                                                'edit_item'         =>  'Edit Image',
                                                'new_item'          =>  'New Image',
                                                'all_items'         =>  'All Images',
                                                'view_item'         =>  'View Image',
                                                'search_items'      =>  'Search Images',
                                                'not_found'         =>  'No Images found',
                                                'not_found_in_trash'=>  'No Images found in Trash', 
                                                'parent_item_colon' =>  '',
                                                'menu_name'         =>  'Images'
                                            ),
                'public'                =>  true,
                'exclude_from_search'   =>  false,
                'publicly_queryable'    =>  true,
                'show_ui'               =>  true,
                'show_in_nav_menus'     =>  true,
                'show_in_menu'          =>  true,
                'menu_position'         =>  1,
                //'menu_icon'               =>  'icon32',
                'capability_type'       =>  'post',
                //'map_meta_cap'            =>  false,
                'hierarchical'          =>  false,
                'supports'              =>  array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields'),
                'register_meta_box_cb'  =>  'add_meta_box_callback',
                'has_archive'           =>  true,
                'query_var'             =>  true,
                'can_export'            =>  true
            )
);
}
add_action('init', 'image_post_type');

function add_meta_box_callback(){
    add_meta_box('image_variations', 'Image Variations', 'image_variations_callback', 'image_post', 'side', 'low');
}

function image_variations_callback(){

}

function add_image_post_type_to_query($query){
    if(is_home() && $query->is_main_query()){
        $query->set( 'post_type', array('post', 'page', 'image_post') );
    }
    return $query;
}
?>
```

Seeing this, I reverted back to my old code and uncommented map_meta_cap once again to get the same "You're not allowed" message.  Upon commenting it out again though it works fine and my final working code is:

```
<?php
function image_post_type(){
    $labels = array(
                'name'              =>  'Images',
                'singlular_name'    =>  'Image',
                'add_new'           =>  'Add New',
                'add_new_item'      =>  'Add New Image',
                'edit_item'         =>  'Edit Image',
                'new_item'          =>  'New Image',
                'all_items'         =>  'All Images',
                'view_item'         =>  'View Image',
                'search_items'      =>  'Search Images',
                'not_found'         =>  'No Images found',
                'not_found_in_trash'=>  'No Images found in Trash', 
                'parent_item_colon' =>  '',
                'menu_name'         =>  'Images'
            );

    $args = array(
                'labels'                =>  $labels,
                'public'                =>  true,
                'exclude_from_search'   =>  false,
                'publicly_queryable'    =>  true,
                'show_ui'               =>  true,
                'show_in_nav_menus'     =>  true,
                'show_in_menu'          =>  true,
                'menu_position'         =>  1,
                //'menu_icon'               =>  'icon32',
                'capability_type'       =>  'post',
                //'map_meta_cap'            =>  false,
                'hierarchical'          =>  false,
                'supports'              =>  array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields'),
                'register_meta_box_cb'  =>  'add_meta_box_callback',
                'has_archive'           =>  true,
                'query_var'             =>  true,
                'can_export'            =>  true
            );

    register_post_type('image_post', $args);
}
add_action('init', 'image_post_type');

function add_meta_box_callback(){
    add_meta_box('image_variations', 'Image Variations', 'image_variations_callback', 'image_post', 'side', 'low');
}

function image_variations_callback(){

}

function add_image_post_type_to_query($query){
    if(is_home() && $query->is_main_query()){
        $query->set( 'post_type', array('post', 'page', 'image_post') );
    }
    return $query;
}
?>
```

**Why though?** How could map_meta_cap be causing this issue when it's set to false?  False is supposed to be the default value.

Thanks for all your help guys, especially you @vancoder!

Answer (score -3):

Here is a working custom_post_type declaration. Try to modify it to fit your needs :)

```
function custom_post_example() { 
    register_post_type( 'my_post_type',
        array('labels' => array(
            'name' => 'my_post_type',
            'singular_name' => 'my_post_type',
            'all_items' => 'All my_post_type',
            'add_new' => 'Add New my_post_type',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New my_post_type',
            'edit' => 'Edit',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Task',
            'new_item' => 'New Task',
            'view_item' => 'View Task',
            'search_items' => 'Search Task',
            'not_found' =>  'Nothing found in the Database.',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'Nothing found in Trash',
            'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent Task Category'
            ),
            'description' => 'This is the my_post_type description',
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'menu_position' => 5,
            'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '......./.......png',
            'rewrite'   => array( 'slug' => 'my_post_type', 'with_front' => true ),
            'has_archive' => true,
            'capability_type' => 'page',
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'author', 'page-attributes')
        )
    );

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_example');
```

Good luck sir!

Edit: More informations here - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Comment: That doesn’t answer the question.

Comment: You neither. Think you for your contribution sir!

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer: **why** could your code solve the problem?

Comment: I mean I've been following the codex the entire time, thanks anyways though.